# How to get a reference to a local variable defined in a method, from inside an event handler method? (in lack of a better title)

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have a tabControl in which I add tabPages each time I click the search button.
The tabControl object also has an event handler for MouseDown, in order to close a tab when that the mouse is hovering a specific tab and clicking on it. The tabcontrol_MouseDown method also cancels a task that is started when clicking on the search button, so that the task will not try to update with a tabPage that has been removed from tabControl with its resultData.

The problem with the below code is that `cts` is an object variable, so it's overwritten everytime I create a new tab with a new CancellationTokenSource. This could work if I only needed to add one single tabPage to tabControl, but I need to add many.

Is there a way I could define and create a cancellation token inside the searchButton_Click method and let tabControl_MouseDown find a reference to it, or is there another way I could solve this?

```
public class Form1 : Form {

    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    private async void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage());
        var resultData = await Task.Run(() => SlowMethod());
        if (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) { /* add resultData to tabPage */ }

    }

    private void tabControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        // - I select the tab being hovered with mouse 
        // - I remove the tab from tabControl
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was just a typo, edited the question. It's about a different matter.

Comment: Can't you just derive from `TabPage`, make `cts` a field and `SlowMethod` an instance method? Then each tab page instance can have its own `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I designed the tabPage in the designer because I needed it to have a specific arrangement of controls inside of it..

Answer (score 2):

Building on hints found in @Steve answer I think I found a sweet, simpler solution which does not require using a global object to store key value pairs of tabPages and their controls.

This is all I needed to do:

```
public class Form1 : Form {

    private async void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        TabPage myNewTab = new TabPage(); 
        myNewTab.Tag = cts;

        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myNewTab);
        var resultData = await Task.Run(() => SlowMethod());
        if (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) { /* add resultData to tabPage */ }

    }

    private void tabControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        // - I select the tab being hovered with mouse 
        // - I remove the tab from tabControl
        CancellationTokenSource cts = (CancellationTokenSource)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag;
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Seems to work as expected.

Comment: This is also a viable solution. It is simpler but of course it binds the list of objects directly to the UI element. No problem at all if you don't need to manipulate or handle that list outside that form. In other words if ever needed I would prefer to loop over the Values of the dictionary instead of the TabPages but I am really nitpicking here

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep your objects in some kind of global storage like a `Dictionary<int, CancellationTokenSource>` where the key is an identifier you give to your tabs and the CancellationTokenSource is related to that specific tab

For example

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    Dictionary<int, CancellationTokenSource> cts = new Dictionary<int, CancellationTokenSource>();
    int tabID = 0;

    private async void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        CancellationTokenSource temp = new CancellationTokenSource();

        tabID++;    
        TabPage tp = new TabPage(); 
        tp.Tag = tabID;
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);

        var resultData = await Task.Run(() => SlowMethod());
        if (!temp.Token.IsCancellationRequested) { /* add resultData to tabPage */ }

       cts.Add(tabID, temp);  
    }

    private void tabControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        // - I select the tab being hovered with mouse 
        // - I remove the tab from tabControl
        TabPage tp = .... select the tabpage from the mouse position
        CancellationTokenSource temp = cts[Convert.ToInt32(tp.Tag)]
        temp.Cancel();
    }
}
```

In this way every single tabPage will be uniquely indentified and the corresponding CancellationTokenSource will be keyed in the dictionary and easily retrieved at the requirend moment.

Comment: I see, thanks. I was hoping for something a bit *nicer* though.. :/  is this the only way?

Comment: Please see my own answer, I think I found an easier solution by just using `Tag`. What do you think?